# anguar array a matriz

Tags: array, angular4, bootstrap-4

mi duda es la siguiente con angular rescato un arreglo de app 100 items y los muestro en la vista con el ngFor, hasta ahi todo bien pero lo que quiero es que en vez de mostrarse de esta manera

- item
- item
- item

se muestre de este modo (como matriz)

- item item item item
- item item item item
- item item item item

como cuando ven la pag de una tienda y aparecen los productos por filas y columnas en vez de una sola columna de productos
,estoy utilizando bootstrap 4 y angular 4.

de ante mano gracias!

Comment: Podrías agregar algo de tu código? Tu html, tu css/scss? Para ver que estas haciendo mal. En un principio te diría que si usas Boostrap 4, uses tamaños de columa de 3 (entrarían 4 por fila, ya que boostrap maneja tamaño hasta 12 por fila), me explico?

Comment: <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Perfil</th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Correo</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr *ngFor="let persona of lstPersonas">
            <td>{{ persona.perfil}}</td>
            <td>{{ persona.nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{ persona.correo}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
este es mi html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que utilizas **Boostrap**, este se basa en un Grid de hasta 12 columnas, por lo tanto puedes dividir tus items en cada columna, de 1 a 12 unidades de ancho. Si cada item ocupa 1 unidad, se verán 12 items por fila, si un item ocupa 12 unidades, sera el único en la fila.

**Pequeño ejemplo explicativo:**

```css
.col-8{
background-color: yellow;
}
.col-4{
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">col-8</div>
  <div class="col-4">col-4</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">1er columna</div>
  <div class="col-4">2da columna</div>
  <div class="col-4">3ra columna</div>
</div>
```

**Como podrías hacer lo que deseas:**

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-4" *ngFor= "let item of items">
         //Mostraría 3 items por fila
        <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-3" *ngFor= "let item of items">
         //Mostraría 4 items por fila
        <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Como viste anteriormente puedes modificar el tamaño de la columna y
>   mostrar tantos items como te sea posible.

Comment: Gracias amigo! me sirvio perfectamente, ahora tengo otra preguntilla, es posible colocarle una paginacion?

Comment: De nada, agradecería el voto positivo. Puedes hacer un simple fixs, para que pagine aunque no seria real, a menos que la hagas con backend también, divide `items` e itera sobre una porción de la misma, cuando pases a la siguiente pagina, cambias el valor de `items` por la otra porción de datos, me explico?

Comment: soy bastante nuevo en este foro, como hago para darte un voto positivo?

Comment: La flecha hacia arriba (^), a la izquierda de la publicación. Necesitas 15 puntos de reputación ([info aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)), hazlo mas adelante. Luego dime si te sirvió la idea de paginacion.